# Is the substitution $\int \sin(x)dx=\operatorname{Im}(\int e^{ix}dx)$ one that can be made and if so why?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Is the substitution $\int \sin(x)dx=\operatorname{Im}(\int e^{ix}dx)$ one that can be made and if so why?
From $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ I know $\operatorname{Im}(e^{ix})=\sin(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R$ but can the $\operatorname{Im}$ operator be moved to the outside of an integral?

Comment: What do you think?\

Comment: Please fix the question, the person who edited it made it even worse.

Comment: What's your definition of the integral of a complex function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you are definitely only integrating over real values of $x$, then the answer is yes. You can see that if we do, for example, the following:

$\begin{eqnarray} \int e^{ix} dx & = & \int (\cos x + i \sin x) dx \\
& = & \int \cos x\ dx + \int i \sin x\ dx \\
& = & \int \cos x\ dx + i \int \sin x\ dx \end{eqnarray}$

Now since both $\int \cos x\ dx$ and $\int \sin x\ dx$ are real-valued (again, assuming the integrals are only happening on the real numbers), you can see that the real and imaginary parts of the expression split on the obvious lines.

However, if you are actually looking at integrals over the complex numbers, it is not true that $\operatorname{Im}(e^{ix}) = \sin x$, and so you have to be more careful. One option is to use the formula $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ which is true for all complex $x$.